# Material Slider delta indicator

Tags: angular-material, material-design

Is it possible to configure a angular material slider like that one in the picture?

[image]

There's only a `invert` option. But this doesn't suit for me.

Comment: What is that supposed to represent?

Comment: It's a audio balance slider. 0 is the default mid point. max value is 100. And min value is -100